# LDAP TLS_REQCERT in WAMP

Tags: php, windows, apache, ssl

I am setting up a development `WAMP` stack and need to set the `TLS_REQCERT` option to never on the `ldap.conf` but there is no such file in the WAMP directory. I also grepped for `'TLS_REQ_CERT'` with the only result being the `php_ldap.dll`. Any thoughts?

Comment: WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP)  Just for information.

Comment: why don't you post ldap.conf file.

Comment: C:\OpenLDAP\sysconf\ldap.conf or c:\ldap.conf

Comment: The problem is that within the WAMP installation directory there is not an OpenLDAP directory or an ldap.conf file. The purpose of developing this configuration is to make a completely encapsulated development stack that can easily be duplicated or moved. LDAP connections are using the Apache module and PHP extension. The security is done by the Apache ssl module and PHP openSSL extension.

Comment: Do you want TLS support in LDAP?

Comment: I want to tell ldaps not to request a certificate.

Comment: I think I miscommunicated the configuration a little bit. I am installing the WAMP bundle from http://www.wampserver.com/en/ for the WAMP stack. I am not individually installing the components. OpenLDAP is not individually installed. The entire stack is within the C:/wamp directory. I want to keep the entire configuration within this directory for easy duplication and deployment.

Comment: You asked windows question and tag "Linux"

Comment: My bad. Fixed. This is the first post I've done in over a year.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/369683/connecting-to-ldaps-with-wamp-server

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand what you are trying to say now. I really would have thought there would be a way to modify the pointed directory for the ldap.conf. Crazy. I've bumped into a couple other issues but as soon as I work them out I will post the configuration that worked for ldaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Satish for the direction on the solution.

Windows 8 x64 Enterprise
WAMP Server(32 bit, PHP 5.4)- http://www.wampserver.com/en/

To enable LDAPS the ldap.conf file must be in C:/OpenLDAP/sysconf/ even if you do not have OpenLDAP installed. Then the TLS_REQCERT option can be set. I had to do the following after installing WAMP Server:

1. Enable Apache ssl_module and ldap_module
2. Uncomment 'Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf' in httpd.conf
3. Copy over crt and key files
4. Configure httpd-ssl.conf
5. Enable the openssl and ldap_php extension in PHP
6. Copy libsasl.dll from the php directory to the apache bin directory
7. Copy ldap.conf to C:/OpenLDAP/sysconf/ldap.conf

And it works!

Comment: I want to add a comment because i was looking now for around 4 days to get that working and there are a lot similar topics on the internet with half of the solution.
Same situation: Windows Server 2K12, Apache 2.4 from apachelounge.com, PHP 7.1 from PHP.net, php_ldap enabled in the php.ini

The path to C:/OpenLDAP/sysconf/ldap.conf seems to be hardcoded in the ldap extension - simple create the file in that directory.
Add there one line: 
TLS_REQCERT never
Restart apache and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line to C:/OpenLDAP/sysconf/ldap.conf worked for me on WAMP 3.1.3 32bit

Answer (score 0):

There is a cleaner and easier way to set the `TLS_REQCERT` option when connecting to ldap.

Try this directly in php:

```php
$ds = ldap_connect('ldaps://myhost:636');
ldap_bind($ds, '{your_ldap_dn}', '{your_ldap_password}')
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER);
```

Consult https://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.constants.php to find the documentation of other options (`LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_ALLOW, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_HARD, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_TRY`).